# How to transform text introduced in a edittext into password style (*****)?

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

I need to do that, like when you put the PIN code in your phone, the numbers transforms into stars (****).

Is there a way to do that in the layout xml file? If not, is there a way to do it with java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. You have to put `android:password="true"` on the xml.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:password

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/Text_password"  
  android:password="true" 
  android:layout_width="80dip"   
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:hint="Password"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it using code:

```
 fieldname.setTransformationMethod(android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```